# replace an avatar head with a 3D scan one of my own

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, virtual-reality

I plan to take some 3D scans of real people's heads and need to put these new heads onto existing generic avatar bodies (happy to buy these if necessary) for use in some basic VR settings (for research purposes) and would like some advice as to possible (time efficient ways) to do this.

The first part, scanning, cleaning and optimizing the head scans will (I hope) be relatively straightforward but I'm unsure about how I can easily replace the avatar head.

I'm less bothered about perfection of the join (though I don't want it to look like frankenstien's monster) but more on saving time (as I'll need to do this with a lot of scans). In particular what to do about the neck and blending in the join.

I don't need facial expressions (though longer term they might be nice)  though I will want to be able to rotate the neck set direction of gaze.

Ideally i'd like to replace the head in code at runtime in Unity rather than hand editing the models but I suspect this might not be possible.

If the process could ultimately be partially automated by scripting that would be even better.

Many thanks,

Comment: Do you need facial movement? Or just the head?

Comment: thanks for asking, I've just updated the op to clarify that I don't need facial expressions, just to be able to turn th eneck to direct the direction of gaze.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a rigged character in Unity, you can see the bones in the hierachy. You can put anything on any bone - for example your head on the neck bone. Just make it a child.
This will move and rotate with the bone - for example in animations or motion-capture (VR).

So I am pretty sure what you want to achieve is as simple as adding the Mesh as a child to the bone.